# How to retrieve last string of a cell delimited by a special string

Tags: google-docs, openoffice-calc

How can I get `Value 1` , `Value 2` and `Value 3` from the following rows (cells) in Google Docs?

```
XYZ1 --> XYZ2 --> Value 1                   
XYZ3 --> XYZ4 --> XYZ5 --> Value 2          
XYZ6 --> Value 3
```

Comment: What is the pattern exactly? I can't work out if you want either the last column of each row or the cells that contain the word "Value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this formula work as you want if your example values are in column A:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(RIGHT(A:A,LEN(A:A)-SEARCH("|",SUBSTITUTE(A:A,"-->","|",(LEN(A:A)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A:A,"-->","")))/LEN("-->")))-LEN("-->"))))`

Comment: very nice! note however that I had to replace A:A with the cell, e.g. A4

Comment: yes, you can use it for a single cell and drag down the column.  Or you should find that pasting the arrayformula(A:A) somewhere in row 1 will output the whole column in a single formula and will update as new values are added to column A.  Example sheet here: https://goo.gl/RT1auq